# Get View from Listview to String

Tags: java, android, regex, string, listview

I have a Listview and I need to get the String values of each row when I click the List view.

**This is my code**

```
public void ListDrwaer() {
List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

try {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("lectureraccount");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsonChildNode.optString("lecturerName");
        String code = jsonChildNode.optString("lecturerCode");
        String outPut = name + "   ---   " + code;
        employeeList.add(createEmployee("lecturer", outPut));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[] { "lecturer" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
    {
        String str = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        System.out.println(str);
    }});
}
```

I **Managed** to get output like this.

```
{lecturer=MAGESWARY A/P MUNIANDI   ---   C-MAGESWARY}
```

My **Question** is how to get output like this

```
C-MAGESWARY
```

Thats all. I am new in programming and not know much. Do i need to change my code completly. If it is, How?
Thank you.

Comment: This is more like a Java question. So you could add the Java tag. This would get more attention from Java experts. I posted an answer that may help and others are helping you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `split` in your `onItemClick` method as below:

```
String str = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
String[] parts = str.split("---");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1]; // This is the part you want
String output = part2.replaceAll("\\s+","") //trim whitespace
String output2 = output.replace("}", ""); // remove the "}" character
System.out.println(output2);
```

Output:

```
C-MAGESWARY
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java question. Look at link [Class String Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Besides the previous answer, look at methods substring, indexOf, and lastIndexof.
You can make it easy on yourself since you have control of the string format in your ListView. Simply add unique characters before your example "C-MAGESWARY", like "!@" . Then you can search the string for those characters. Remember this technique for future apps.